# Intuition behind continuity at $0$ implies continuity everywhere.

Tags: real-analysis

I have been wondering about this for a while, but I don't really see a clear connection aside from the mathematical details.

1. Could someone please provide the intuition behind this common occurrence in analysis?
2. What are the conditions for this to take place in general?

Comment: For *linear maps*, I presume.

Comment: Does it automatically fail for non-linear map?

Comment: Not necessarily. It is however a quite rare occurrence among classes of functions studied in analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $f:X\to Y$ linear let $B_\epsilon:=B(0,\epsilon)$ an open ball centered at zero for some $\epsilon>0$, and $x\in X$. Then

$$f(B_\epsilon)+f(x)=f(B_\epsilon +x)=f(B(x,\epsilon))$$

Then the behavior of $f$ in a $\epsilon$-neighborhood of zero represent the behavior of $f$ at every other $\epsilon$-neighborhood.